# Adding a text in a plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How is it possible to add a name in a part of a plot (e.g. in the bottom) alike the image in below:

[image]

Comment: [text()?](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html)

Comment: @Adam , Thanks, Is there an easier way for coordination specification in the area for doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By customizing the idea from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/465720-help-with-adding-the-text-location) we get

```
x = -10:10;
y = (rand(1,21)-0.5)*20;
figure
plot(x, y, 'pg')
NE = [max(xlim) max(ylim)]-[diff(xlim) diff(ylim)]*0.05;
SW = [min(xlim) min(ylim)]+[diff(xlim) diff(ylim)]*0.05;
NW = [min(xlim) max(ylim)]+[diff(xlim) -diff(ylim)]*0.05;
SE = [max(xlim) min(ylim)]+[-diff(xlim) diff(ylim)]*0.05;

%% Top
text(NE(1), NE(2), 'Top Right', 'VerticalAlignment','top','HorizontalAlignment',...
    'right', 'FontSize',20, 'color', 'red')

text(NE(1)/2 + NW(1)/2, NE(2)/2 + NW(2)/2, 'Top Center', 'VerticalAlignment',...
    'top', 'HorizontalAlignment','center', 'FontSize',20, 'color', 'red')

text(NW(1), NW(2), 'Top Left', 'VerticalAlignment','top', 'HorizontalAlignment',...
    'left', 'FontSize',20, 'color', 'red')

%% Bottom
text(SW(1), SW(2), 'Bottom Left', 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', 'HorizontalAlignment',...
'left', 'FontSize',20, 'color', 'blue')
text(SW(1)/2 + SE(1)/2, SW(2)/2 + SE(2)/2, 'Bottom Center', 'VerticalAlignment',...
    'bottom', 'HorizontalAlignment','center', 'FontSize',20, 'color', 'blue')
text(SE(1), SE(2), 'Bottom Right', 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', 'HorizontalAlignment',...
    'right', 'FontSize',20, 'color', 'blue')

%% Middle
text(NW(1)/2 + SW(1)/2,NW(2)/2 + SW(2)/2, 'Middle Left', 'VerticalAlignment',...
    'top', 'HorizontalAlignment','left', 'FontSize',20)
text(NE(1)/2 + SE(1)/2,NE(2)/2 + SE(2)/2, 'Middle Right', 'VerticalAlignment',...
    'top', 'HorizontalAlignment','right', 'FontSize',20)

text(NE(1)/2 + NW(1)/2 + SW(1)/2 + SE(1)/2,NE(2)/2 + NW(2)/2 + SW(2)/2 + SE(2)/2  , ...
    'Middle Center', 'VerticalAlignment','top', 'HorizontalAlignment','center', 'FontSize',20)

set(gca,'FontSize',20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would suggest using the `title()` or photoshopping the text in post-generation, because `MATLAB`'s implementation has always bee clunky. That being said, `MATLAB` does have the ability to add text to a figure via the `text()` command.

The general format is:

```
text( x, y, '(b) PASCAL-S' );
```

where the `x` and `y` describe the location on the plot that you want to place the text.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Is there an easier way for coordination specification in the area for doing so?

Comment: Not particularly, which is why I mentioned that MATLAB is terrible at adding text to plots. People have hacks and tricks to automatically assign `x` and `y` that you can probably find on the web, but they do not always work for every specific situation